# Why can't move the item to get the desired result of factorization?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The polynomial is:

```
b^2 x1 y0 - b^2 x2 y0 + b^2 x0 y1 + b^2 x2 y1 - b^2 x0 y2 - 
  b^2 x1 y2 + a^2 x1 y0 λ - a^2 x2 y0 λ + 
  a^2 x0 y1 λ - a^2 x2 y1 λ - a^2 x0 y2 λ + 
  a^2 x1 y2 λ == 0
```

want to get this result as follows:

```
b^2 x1 y0 - b^2 x2 y0 + b^2 x0 y1 - b^2 x0 y2 + a^2 x1 y0 \[Lambda] - 
  a^2 x2 y0 \[Lambda] + a^2 x0 y1 \[Lambda] - 
  a^2 x0 y2 \[Lambda] + (x2 y1 - x1 y2) (b^2 - a^2 \[Lambda]) == 0
```

How can I correct an error using the following code?

```
b^2 x1 y0 - b^2 x2 y0 + b^2 x0 y1 + b^2 x2 y1 - b^2 x0 y2 - 
   b^2 x1 y2 + a^2 x1 y0 \[Lambda] - a^2 x2 y0 \[Lambda] + 
   a^2 x0 y1 \[Lambda] - a^2 x2 y1 \[Lambda] - a^2 x0 y2 \[Lambda] + 
   a^2 x1 y2 \[Lambda] == 0 /. 
 k_.*((x2y1 : _)) - k_.*((x1y2 : _)) + t_ == 0 :> 
  k*((x2y1) - (x1y2)) + t == 0
```

but get the error result:

```
b^2 (x1 y0 - x2 y0) + b^2 x0 y1 + b^2 x2 y1 - b^2 x0 y2 - b^2 x1 y2 + 
  a^2 x1 y0 \[Lambda] - a^2 x2 y0 \[Lambda] + a^2 x0 y1 \[Lambda] - 
  a^2 x2 y1 \[Lambda] - a^2 x0 y2 \[Lambda] + a^2 x1 y2 \[Lambda] == 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderately to very complicated algebra is usually better done with algebra functions and not with patterns.  In this case `PolynomialReduce[]` is designed for the OP's operation.

```
Flatten[
   PolynomialReduce[
    b^2 x1 y0 - b^2 x2 y0 + b^2 x0 y1 + b^2 x2 y1 - b^2 x0 y2 - 
     b^2 x1 y2 + a^2 x1 y0 \[Lambda] - a^2 x2 y0 \[Lambda] + 
     a^2 x0 y1 \[Lambda] - a^2 x2 y1 \[Lambda] - a^2 x0 y2 \[Lambda] +
      a^2 x1 y2 \[Lambda], {x2 y1 - x1 y2}, {x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2}]
   ] . {x2 y1 - x1 y2, 1} == 0
(*
x2 y0 (-b^2 - a^2 \[Lambda]) + x0 y2 (-b^2 - a^2 \[Lambda]) +
  (x2 y1 - x1 y2) (b^2 - a^2 \[Lambda]) + 
  x1 y0 (b^2 + a^2 \[Lambda]) + x0 y1 (b^2 + a^2 \[Lambda]) == 0
*)
```

Or (this gives the indicated desired form):

```
Flatten[
   ExpandAll@ PolynomialReduce[
     b^2 x1 y0 - b^2 x2 y0 + b^2 x0 y1 + b^2 x2 y1 - b^2 x0 y2 - 
      b^2 x1 y2 + a^2 x1 y0 \[Lambda] - a^2 x2 y0 \[Lambda] + 
      a^2 x0 y1 \[Lambda] - a^2 x2 y1 \[Lambda] - 
      a^2 x0 y2 \[Lambda] + a^2 x1 y2 \[Lambda], {x2 y1 - x1 y2}, 
     {x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2}]
   ] . {x2 y1 - x1 y2, 1} == 0
(*
b^2 x1 y0 - b^2 x2 y0 + b^2 x0 y1 - b^2 x0 y2 + a^2 x1 y0 \[Lambda] - 
  a^2 x2 y0 \[Lambda] + a^2 x0 y1 \[Lambda] - 
  a^2 x0 y2 \[Lambda] + (x2 y1 - x1 y2) (b^2 - a^2 \[Lambda]) == 0
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = b^2 x1 y0 - b^2 x2 y0 + b^2 x0 y1 + b^2 x2 y1 - b^2 x0 y2 - 
   b^2 x1 y2 + a^2 x1 y0 λ - a^2 x2 y0 λ + 
   a^2 x0 y1 λ - a^2 x2 y1 λ - a^2 x0 y2 λ + 
   a^2 x1 y2 λ == 0

#[[1, 1 ;; -3]] + Factor[#[[1, -2 ;;]]] == #[[2]] &@
 Collect[expr, {x1 y2, x2 y1}]
```

> b^2 x1 y0 - b^2 x2 y0 + b^2 x0 y1 - b^2 x0 y2 + a^2 x1 y0 λ -
> a^2 x2 y0 λ + a^2 x0 y1 λ -    a^2 x0 y2 λ +
> (x2 y1 - x1 y2) (b^2 - a^2 λ) == 0

Comment: ```#[[1, 1 ;; -3]] + Factor[#[[1, -2 ;;]]] &```What does this sentence mean?

Comment: Take a look at docs for [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html). Please study the answers that you receive and invest time in learning the software. Thanks.

Comment: This code seems to lack universality, and it cannot be decomposed into formulas containing x2 y1- x1 y2,such as:expr1 = a x1 y2 - 7 x2 y1 + a x1 y2 - 7 x2 y1 + x^2 + 2 x y + y^2
#[[1, 1 ;; -3]] + Factor[#[[1, -2 ;;]]] &@
 Collect[expr1, {x1 y2, x2 y1}]